# List, IList, IEnumerable, IQueryable, ICollection, which is most flexible return type?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, architecture, collections

I've seen this question posted here previously but I'm not satisfied that I understand the complete ramifications. The problem is what return type should a data layer that uses linq-to-sql return for maximum flexibility and query ability. This is what I've read/found:

1. IEnumerable is limited and only allows for read forward operation. IEnumerable is the most generic. What I've found is that IEnumerable does allow query operations vs the extension syntax.
2. List allows for most flexibility because of insert operations.
3. Collections should be used instead of list to enable read only collections.
4. IQueryable should never be used, it should be "used and turned off". IQueryable doesn't return a list but generates a query syntax for database.

I feel I have a better feel for the trade offs but still not sure about a few things:

1. Why would I choose the interface variants over the concrete types? I.e IList or ICollection vs List or Collection. What benefit would I get?
2. I see that the extension operations work but will the expanded query syntax work as well?
3. Someone suggested I use AsQueryable() before. But, why would I do this if I don't have connection to the database? It seems the extension methods work regardless.

Comment: Remove the "List" class from your question. IList, IEnumerable, IQueryable, etc. are all interfaces whereas "List" is a class. The "List" class is an apple among oranges in your question.

Comment: @Stargazer that is part of the question, what is the benefit of using IList vs List. I'm writing up some examples now.

Comment: @Curtis, that is what I am saying: List implements IList, and therefore *is* an IList. They are apples and oranges, and I don't feel you understand the difference. A better way to rephrase a question involving the difference between the two would be, "What is the difference between returning a class and returning an interface?"

Comment: @Stargazer I know what an interface is and a class is. I know that a class implements the interface and the interface serves as the contract. My question is what is the tangible difference (or is there a tangible difference) in returning IList<t> vs List<t>?

Comment: @Stargazer and if there is no tangible difference then how would one rationally choose the best option?

Comment: The difference is in the capabilities that an IList gives you. IList is an interface, thus it allows you to abstract what you are actually returning. If your function returns an IList and one day you decide to change how the function works, then you can change it to return something that *implements* IList. If on the other hand you return a List, you are permanently bound to that decision. To change it, you will have to change anything that relied on that function returning a List. Bottom line: use interfaces for parameters and return values. Use concrete types within functions.

Comment: I would say remove IQueryable from that list, it's a different beast altogether.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Collections are not generally very useful for DAL returns, because a collection does not implicitly guarantee order. It's just a bucket of items. An IList, on the other hand, does implicitly guarantee order. So we're down to IEnumerable or IList. The next question would be: is the List object "live"? i.e., is it connected to the data backing so that when you add an item to the IList, it will be reflected in the DB? For LINQ-to-SQL, this is not the case. Rather, you're supposed to attach entities to the tables. So unless you supply this additional wiring, a List is superfluous. Stick with IEnumerable.

Comment: @Rex Okay this makes sense. Why would you return IList over using the concrete List? What is the benefit for the cases it makes sense?

Comment: @Rex: While I agree with your conclusion, respectfully, I'd suggest that the DAL shouldn't be ordering collections. That belongs to the client/consumer/business logic. i.e. `MyDal.ListCustomers().OrderBy(InvoiceDate)`.

Comment: @P.Campbell I'd be concerned about the speed of this operation especially when not required.

Comment: @Curtis you should always return an interface, so you can change the logic inside the return object without anyone knowing or caring.

Comment: @Rex You can change the logic inside return object without anyone knowing or caring anyway, that's the point of encapsulation. ;0

Comment: @Rex The real purpose of the interface is to allow type variance, not encapsulation which is provided by the object. Type variance could also be solved by inheriting from a common base class but interfaces probably became preferred in .NET because of single inheritance.

Comment: @Curtis we're saying the same thing. If the implementation is hidden behind an interface, it could be anything. Also, never inherit from List. It will cause headaches.

Comment: "Collections are not generally very useful for DAL returns, because a collection does not implicitly guarantee order." - But neither does IEnumerable, your recommendation.  Personally I'd only return IEnumerable if the implementation might be lazy-evaluated, unlikely for a DAL result.  Returning IList guarantees that the caller can enumerate the result more than once, as well as providing a Count property.

Comment: @Joe IEnumerable doesn't imply order or lack of order; it's up to the implementation. But `Collection` actually does imply a general lack of order.

Answer (score 8):

You should always return an interface rather than a concrete type, this goes without saying as it specifies the behaviour allowed without tying the consumer to a specific implementation.

In terms of which interface to return, you should think about the purpose of the method and the intentions of the caller. If you return a collection, should the caller be able to alter the collection? e.g. add/remove items? if all they need to do is enumerate it (do a foreach) then you should just return an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

1) It's best to return an IList so that the results can be put into any object that implements that interface, rather than forcing the caller into using a List.  For example, the caller might wish to have the results returned to an ArrayList, this wouldn't be possible if you had the results returned to a List.  ArrayList doesn't inherit from List, but it does implement IList.

Comment: Good answer except its wrong.  The caller doesn't get to control how the results are returned.  If I have a method "IList GetCustomers()" and the concrete type returned is actually "List" the caller can't say ArrayList results = GetCustomers();  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539436/cast-interface-to-its-concrete-implementation-object-or-vice-versa