# Instanciate Interface to new Class C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading [WebHostBuilder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/b6da89f54cff11474f17486cdc55c2f21f2bbd6b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs) class.

It's not clear to me why `private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;`

was instanciated in the constructor as `_hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment();`

Here is the (modified for succinctness) code:

```
public class WebHostBuilder
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public WebHostBuilder()
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found this question useful.
[Cast interface to its concrete implementation object or vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539436/cast-interface-to-its-concrete-implementation-object-or-vice-versa)

Comment: readonly just means, that there is not accessability in modifying this member. so if a class has an readonly member of a custom type with a name, then you can set the name to a new value from a instance of the class with the readonly meber but you **can NOT** assign the readonly member itselfe to a new value

Comment: What exactly is not clear? What was your expectation from this code instead?

Comment: I don´t understand the question neither. Where *else* did you expected the value to be set? I guess you *have* to set a value if you want (and you definitly want) to avoid a NullReferenceException afterwards when accessing the field.

Comment: Guys I think he is asking why a variable of type ```IHostingEnvironment``` is instantiated with ```HostingEnvironment```? Perhaps he needs to read up on interfaces and concrete types.

Comment: Or are you confused why the initialization doesn´t happen just in place of the declaration, so where you declare the field as `private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment();`

Comment: `readonly` simply means that the member can only be assigned in the constructor of the class or on the member itself. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @GeoffJames - Or directly on the field itself.

Comment: Ah, good catch @Enigmativity - that, too. Thanks - edited :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you´re confused that the value is set in the constructor instead where you declare the field. In your example you could easily and probably also validly write the following:

```
 private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment();
```

This will have exactly the same effect, as it is implicitly converted to a constructor-statement by the compiler. So both are similar.

However there *exists* a need to use the constructor when you don´t know the value to be used at compile-time. Imagine the constructor of `HostingEnvironment` expects an integer to be passed:

```
public class WebHostBuilder
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment // = new HostingEnvironment(whatToSetHere ???);

    public WebHostBuilder(int i)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment(i);
    }
}
```

During compile-time you don´t know the value to be provided for the `HostingEnvironment`-constructor. So you provide it as early as you get it, in this case in the constructor of your own class.

In addition the `readonly`-modifier simply states that you can *set* the value for a member only within the constructor (or in place with the declaration, which is converted to a constructor-call, remember what I´ve mentioned above).

Comment: Is it the same with  `private readonly HostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment = new HostingEnvironment();`  why the interface `IHostingEnvironment` is set as `new HostingEnvironment();`